# Proofs on inequalities of real numbers

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, real-numbers

So I have these inequalities (statements) to prove:

$x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

$\vert xy \vert \leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2)$

$x,y \geq 0 \implies xy \leq \frac{1}{4}(x + y)^2$

I know that I have to use "The Axioms of the real numbers" but I don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: Note:  squares, such as $(x-y)^2$ and $(x+y)^2,$ are non-negative

Comment: $(x\pm y)^2\geq 0\Rightarrow x^2+y^2\geq \pm 2xy$

Comment: @Ameryr:  use \pm for $\pm$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Done

Answer (score 1):

Use that $$(|x|-|y|)^2=x^2+y^2-2|xy|$$

Comment: Like this?
$(\vert x \vert -\vert y \vert)^2 = x^2 +y^2-2\vert xy\vert \iff$

$(\vert x \vert -\vert y \vert)^2 + 2\vert xy\vert = x^2 +y^2$

$\implies 2\vert xy\vert \leq x^2 +y^2 $

$\iff \vert xy\vert \leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2 +y^2)$